# I have a few problems with my cart in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I've integrated the codeigniter shopping cart class into my project and I've run into some problems regarding the accounting. The first problem I have is that I have three separate price accounting arrays. One is for the product price, another for the subtotal, another including subtotal + another option. I have no trouble adding items to the cart however, it's just the update that sometimes messes up. Another problem I have is that if I have multiple items in my cart that only the latest added(at the bottom) can be updated.

The update itself works it's that it works the wrong way, let's say I have a product that costs `0.01653800`, my added option to the price costs `0.00253000`. So when I update my quantity, the sub-total(excluding the added option) multiplies fine, however the total price shows something entirely different, it shows `0.03813600`. This is obviously not correct, if you do the math.

This is my code in the view:

```
<?php echo form_open('main/update'); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="update_row_id" value="<?php echo $items["rowid"]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="update_max_qty" value=<?php echo $items["options"]["max_stock"]; ?>">
<input type="text" name="update_qty" value="<?php echo $items["qty"]; ?>">
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'submit'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

This is my controller function:

```
if (isset($_POST['update_submit'])) {


  foreach($this->cart->contents() as $updates):

      $total = $this->input->post('update_qty') * $updates['options']['actual_price'];

    $data = array(
      'rowid' =>  $this->input->post('update_row_id'),
      'qty' =>  $this->input->post('update_qty'),
      'options' =>  array(
        'subtotal'  =>  $total,
        'distribution'  =>  $updates['options']['distribution'],
        'notes'  =>  $updates['options']['notes'],
        'extras_price'  =>  $updates['options']['extras_price'],
        'product_price'  =>  $updates['options']['product_price'],
        'max_stock' =>  $updates['options']['max_stock']
      ),
      'subtotal'  =>  $updates['options']['extras_price'] + $total
    );
  endforeach;

    if ($this->input->post('update_qty') > $this->input->post('update_max_qty')) {
      exit("You can't buy more than ".$this->input->post('update_max_qty')." of this item!");
    }
    else {
      redirect('main/cart_page');
    }
  }
}
```

I'm assuming I can only update one item because of the way I've assigned the hidden input containing the rowid. If so how can I change that. And why don't the price options add up the way I desire?

Comment: The docs say: "Important: The Cart library is DEPRECATED and should not be used. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility." see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html

Comment: Yea I'm aware of that, but it's easy to use and I cannot  see any problems with it!